# Where is the function: trace_io_uring_submit_sqe in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, io-uring

Recently, I'm tracing the io_uring in Linux kernel. I found a function `trace_io_uring_submit_sqe` was called in [io_uring.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/dfa377c35d70c31139b1274ec49f87d380996c42/fs/io_uring.c#L6635). Through searching symbol on Github mirror repository or on [elixir.bootlin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/C/ident/trace_io_uring_submit_sqe), I can't found the definition of its. Are there any other way to find it or it just doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symbol is created dynamically using a macro, that's why you can't find it in the sources.

The file [trace/events/io_uring.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/fs/io_uring.c#L84) is included on line 84, and it contains [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/trace/events/io_uring.h#L334) usage of macro `TRACE_EVENT`:

```c
TRACE_EVENT(io_uring_submit_sqe, //(...more code)
```

The `TRACE_EVENT` macro is defined in [linux/tracepoint.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L552) using another macro, `DECLARE_TRACE`. `DECLARE_TRACE` is defined in the same file on [line 418](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L418) and uses `__DECLARE_TRACE` which is defined in the same file again, on line [241](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L241) or [341](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L341) depending on the value of the macro `TRACEPOINTS_ENABLED` on [line 162](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L162).

The `__DECLARE_TRACE` macro begins with:

```c
#define __DECLARE_TRACE(name, proto, args, cond, data_proto)        \
    extern int __traceiter_##name(data_proto);          \
    DECLARE_STATIC_CALL(tp_func_##name, __traceiter_##name);    \
    extern struct tracepoint __tracepoint_##name;           \
    static inline void trace_##name(proto)              \
    //(... more code)
```

This line specifically:

```c
static inline void trace_##name(proto)
```

expands into a declaration of a `static inline void` function whose name is the `name` passed down from `TRACE_EVENT` with a prefix `trace_` prepended to it (`##` is used for string concatenation in macros), which in your case results in a name of `trace_io_uring_submit_sqe`.

[Here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/trace/tracepoints.rst) you may find documentation of tracing.

**How to recognize dynamic code generation using macros?**

If you look throughout the `io_uring.c` file you will find a few functions with names following the formula of `trace_ + some_function`. At the same time, none of them can be found in the source code. This often means these symbols are generated using a macro. In such cases you could try looking for the common prefix instead of the whole symbol. If you search for `trace_` on github you will find [multiple similar macros](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=trace_) which could have given you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me check one thing. Can I claim that `trace_io_uring_submit_sqe` do the things between [line:246~256](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/linux/tracepoint.h#L246)?

Comment: Comment at [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14-rc6/source/include/trace/events/io_uring.h#L334) seems to imply that `io_uring_submit_sqe` not only dump information.

Comment: Yes, lines 246 to 256 define the body of the function which is being declared by the macro, so this is what the function will do once called.